# Do I have to migrate Realm database If I added a field with @Ignore annotation?

Tags: android, migration, realm, schema, field

In current schema I have a class User. I want to add another field in that class that I do not want to persist, but I want to fetch it from the backend and store it somewhere else.

I use the @Ignore annotation on that field, but I don't know if I need to migrate the db, did the schema changed?

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is unclear; you said - *I want to add another field to that class that I do not want to persist* - and then - *but I want to fetch it*. If a field is not persisted (meaning data is NOT saved e.g. persisted, to Realm) there would be no way to fetch it since it was not persisted to begin with. Can you maybe clarify what you mean? Update the question itself please, so it's clear to other readers.

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry if I made that unclear. I thought that fetching from the server and persisting to the local database are not the same thing. But anyways, I updated the question to be more understandable.

Comment: This question still conflicts with itself. If a field is added (a property)  that doesn't persist then there's nothing to fetch; the data wasn't written to begin with. In other words there are two kinds of properties in a realm object; persistable, which are stored in Realm, and then non persisted, which are just regular code properties (vars) which are not stored in Realm. Persisted (also called managed properties) are stored in Realm. You cannot retrieve a regular property from Realm because it was not stored in Realm in the first place. Does that clarify things?

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My question was: "If I add one regular code property (var) which I do not want to persist (I used @Ignore annotation) to the already created class (schema), does that mean that scema is somehow changed, and I need to make a migration? Or realm ignores the added var and migration is not needed? "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the question (from comments)

> If I add one regular code property (var) which I do not want to
> persist (I used @Ignore annotation) to the already created class
> (schema), does that mean that scema is somehow changed, and I need to
> make a migration?

No, ignored properties are just that, ignored. That are not managed by Realm in any way.

By default, Realm manages properties defined in your Realm object model and Managed properties are stored or updated in the database. Ignored properties are not stored to the database. You can mix managed and ignored properties within a class.

So, in this example if we have a Dog class with a managed property `name`

```
class Dog : RealmObject {
    var name: String = ""
}
```

and if a property is added to store a tempId, which does not need to be managed

```
class Dog : RealmObject {
    var name: String = ""

    @Ignore
    var tempId: Int = 0 // Ignored property
}
```

This will not cause a change in schema, nor need a migration as there's no data to migrate.